# Can I run SignalR hub through Azure API Management?

Tags: c#, azure, signalr, azure-api-management

I have the same question as [this guy](http://forums.asp.net/t/2006354.aspx?hosting%20SignalR%20Hub%20through%20API%20Management%20platform%20Azure%20API%20Management%20): can I run my SignalR hub through the Azure API management service?

[image]

I cannot seem to configure it in the service: it only allows me to forward HTTP/HTTPS traffic. That matches the answer of the person in the forum post. 
I followed the link down to the Microsoft forum, but it seems the question wasn't followed up there. Since the response was from 2014, I thought - maybe it is possible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Management supports Web Sockets now.

1. Navigate to the API Management instance in the Azure Portal
2. Add Api
3. Under Define a new API, select WebSocket
4. In the dialog box, select Full and complete the required form fields
5. Click create

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/websocket-api?tabs=portal

(WebSocket APIs are not supported yet in the Consumption tier.)

Comment: That's good to know. Unfortunately, it requires setting up a separate WebSocket API endpoint in API Management. AFAIK, this will not be a solution if you use SignalR embedded in your API (i.e. have a single operation like `/hub` on the same api).

Answer (score 5):

websocket is currently not supported in Azure API Management. Please feel free to raise a feature request: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/filters/new

Comment: Done: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/8425941-allow-signalr-through-azure-api-management. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As we know, the Azure API Management [still doesn't support WebSockets](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/6060419-socket-full-duplex-support-in-addition-to-http#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D)

> Dec 6, 2016:
> Rest assured we still have this request in mind and are continually
> reviewing it. Please keep your feedback coming!

If you are using [Azure SignalR Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/signalr-service/) then you can follow the way described  by @lazizanie because your SignalR service should only provide a negotiate endpoint:

[image]

Let's say you have the Hub named **myHub** in ASP.NET Core 3.1

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapHub<Hub>("/myHub"));
```

Then add operation in API management `URL=POST /myHub/negotiate` with `negotiateVersion` query param

or use JSON editor and add it to `paths`

```
"/myHub/negotiate": {
    "post": {
        "summary": "SignalR negotiate ",
        "operationId": "signalr-negotiate",
        "parameters": [{
            "name": "negotiateVersion",
            "in": "query",
            "schema": {
                "type": ""
            }
        }],
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the Backed set host of your SignalR service like `https://myHubSignalR.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com`

Comment: websockets are now supported in APIM: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/websocket-api.  

Does that mean we should be able to leverage APIM to establish connections with signalR service?

Comment: @NSjonas yes, we have already moved to it

Answer (score 2):

It depends, websockets are not supported, but if you use an azure signalr ressource, only the negotiate request,; which is a basic post to your hub, has to go through your APIM, and the rest of the coms (the websocket requests) will be directly with the azure signalr ressource.